# Bluetooth Speaker only plays sound when media is detected in the notification shade. (Windows 11)

Tags: audio, windows-11, bluetooth, media

I have **Windows 11 Laptop** (*ASUS ROG Strix)*, **Bluetooth Speaker (BT Speaker)** (*BoAt Stone 352*), **Wireless Headphones** (*OnePlus Wireless Z2*).

The Problem is **NOT** faced when I use the inbuilt Speaker of my laptop or the OnePlus Headphones, **but when I connect the Stone 352 (BT Speaker)**.

**Problem Description** (as much as I have Observed):

1. Sound is only played through BT Speaker whenever the Windows 11 detects media playing in the [notification shade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ0uy.jpg) (Like here Spotify is detected).
2. BT Speaker gives output of every sound from laptop but only when the media detected in the notification shade is NOT paused. If media is paused the sound also stops.
3. For example, If I have Chrome-Youtube (Paused), and Spotify (Playing) and VLC (Paused). then the sound of laptop is only heard when the notification shade has spotify selected, if in case I changed the spotify in notification to Chrome-Youtube (which here is currently paused) then the output of sound is stopped.
4. But, If Spotify (Playing) and VLC (Playing) and the notification shade has spotify detected (which is the only option) then the sound of Spotify and VLC both is heard.
5. Windows 11 detects some of the apps in notification shade. VLC is not detected. That means whenever I want to play VLC then I need to play something else (on mute) like, Chrome/Spotify on sound (0%) put that on notification shade (in front using the top right arrow)
6. I have to switch the detected media in notification shade everytime when I switch tabs or pause the youtube playback (most of the time) and it's frustrating.

Samples: [ [Sound is heard from BT Speaker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPRyg.jpg) ][ [Sound is **NOT** heard from BT Speaker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob62N.jpg) ]

This Problem **never** occurs in case on OnePlus Headphones, they play everything irrespective of what is detected in the Windows 11 notifications shade.

I wish my Bluetooth Speakers too worked like my Bluetooth headphones :(